# MySQL 5.7.26 weird issue... cannot set datetime to: 2020-03-21 00:00:00

Tags: mysql

I cannot insert this date in my table: `2020-03-21`!

I mean I can set 20 and 22 just fine, but when I set 21 it fails with Error:

> Incorrect datetime value: '2020-03-21 00:00:00'

Using PDO I get:

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2020-03-21 00:00:00' for column 'when' at row 1")

I'm really confused, so any help is appreciated!

**Server version: 5.7.26 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)**

**Protocol version: 10**

#### Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `when` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

#### Queries:

**This works just fine:**

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`when`) VALUES ('2020-03-20 00:00:00');
```

**This returns ERROR:**

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`when`) VALUES ('2020-03-21 00:00:00');
```

> Incorrect datetime value: '2020-03-21 00:00:00' for column 'when' at row 1

[image]

Same Error using phpMyAdmin

[image]

Comment: Show the exact query you're running. And a table schema as well.

Comment: @zerkms Not sure why I got down-voted, it is not related to table and query... added a simple example table anyway.

Comment: not reproducible: https://pastebin.com/SwiQb47Y

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for checking, I'm guessing it's related to my environment then? https://i.imgur.com/KHTHHjx.png

Comment: It is weird that everything is fine when I use `2020-03-20 00:00:00` or any other date and this only happens with `2020-03-21 00:00:00`... really confused right now. Work with this: https://i.imgur.com/U2MYbjy.png (only changed 21 to 20)

Comment: Have you tried to type the whole datetime manually from scratch in a query?

Comment: @zerkms Yes, multiple times

Comment: Can you try to change your datatype from timestamp to datetime and see if the insert works?

Comment: @Vlam Yes, I tested and it works fine with datetime. But the field is timestamp, and also it has no issues for all other dates, so I'm wondering what caused it...

Comment: Run `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global, @@SESSION.sql_mode session` and see what you get.

Comment: What is your server timezone? You most likely have some sort of daylight saving kicking in, and maybe this particular hour does not exist at all in your timezone

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya You are 100% correct! thank you for helping me understand this.

Comment: Welcome. You can put as an answer with your timezone .. will help someone else in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MadhurBhaiya answered this as a comment,

The issue was "Daylight Saving", basically that time didn't exist for my server timezone.

Fixed it by changing timezone to UTC (which doesn't have Daylight Saving)

Also, please note that this issue only happens for `TIMESTAMP` field (doesn't happen for `DATETIME`)

Comment: I do not understand how a particular time can not exists because of some daylight savings. Can someone explain me how this happens?

Comment: @BhaumikBhatt On a specific date, exactly on `00:00:00` the time is changed to `01:00:00` for [daylight saving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), and therefore the time range `00:00:00 - 00:59:59` doesn't exist for that date! some timezones don't have daylight saving, such as UTC

Comment: *"On a specific date, exactly on 00:00:00 the time is changed to 01:00:00"* @J.Doe then `00:00:00` should exist logicalwise...  `00:00:00.000001` to `00:59:59` can't exists... MySQL timestamp datatype handles this a bit wierd if `00:00:00` was not possible...

Comment: @RaymondNijland Well I'm confused too, but I think 00:00:00 is represented as `01:00:00` instead. it was good to know this MySQL issue though which can cause some serious issues... will always stick to UTC. I think it was better if they automatically converted those times for example 00:30 to 01:30 on that date instead of returning an error, or at least a setting for that would help.

Comment: That's crazy but your answer helped me! My DB doesn't let me use `'2020-03-29 02:00:00'` (CEST timezone is configured on the server), MySQL 8.0